# Binary Search Homework

Tags: java, binary-search

It's late, I'm tired and forgot I had java homework. Last question is to write a Java program to find the value 45.3 from this list `{-3,10,5,24,45.3,10.5}` using the binary search method.

Normally I'd be fine but I really don't want to have to rush this in the morning and I'm too tired to think straight so hopefully someone can help at least a little bit.

Here is the code:

```
public class questionTwelve
{
    public static int binarySearch(int x)
    {
        int low = 0;
        int high = a.length - 1;
        int mid;
        int foundindex;

        while (low <= high)
        {
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (a[mid].compareTo (x) < 0)
                low = mid + 1;
            else if (a[mid].compareTo (x) > 0)
                high = mid - 1;
            else
                foundindex = mid.getIndex;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a[];
        a[0] = -3;
        a[1] = 5;
        a[2] = 10;
        a[3] = 10.5;
        a[4] = 24;
        a[5] = 45.3;

        System.out.println("Value 45.3 found at index " + binarySearch(45.3));
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Also, put code in the question, not on an external site

Comment: To me "I forgot I had homework" is just another way of saying "I put off doing my homework until the last minute".  Neither get my sympathy vote.

Comment: An additional thought in addition to my answer - you may want to implement a sorting algorithm (if you're doing searching, you've probably covered sorting as well) to order your list, rather than hard coding it in your main method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to store 10.5 and 45.3, which aren't integers, in a list of integers. That's problem one. You're then trying to pass 45.3 (which still isn't an integer) to a method that accepts an integer as an argument.

Inside that method, you're trying to use compareTo on an integer value, just use the standard < and > operators.

You're then trying to use mid.getIndex - not sure what getIndex is, but it's not anything I've ever used with an int. Your method also doesn't return anything. You'll want to `return mid` when `a[mid] == x`, and then after the while loop, `return -1` (to signify that the number isn't in the list) if it's never hit the other return statement.

Comment: Additionally `a[mid].compareTo (x)` won't work, since `a[mid]` is an int and not an Integer. Just use `a[mid] < x` and `a[mid] > x`.

Comment: Ok now the last problem is binarySearch(double[],double) in questionTwelve cannot be applied to (double,double) referring to this line System.out.println("Value 45.3 found at index " + binarySearch(a[6], 45.3));

Comment: Figured it out nevermind. Thanks a ton for the help guys.